# Quick Hessian matrix and gradient calculation?

Tags: matrix, calculus-and-analysis

I am absolutely new to Mathematica and I actually want to try implementing a [little optimization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) .

Long story short assuming I have a predefined two-variable function f(x,y) I want to calculate a [Hessian matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html)  and a gradient symbolically. Then I want to be able to quickly plug specific x,y values into them.

How is it done in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please show some effort. We are always glad to help newcomers here, as far as we aren't taken for a coding service.

Comment: First of all, *Mathematica* already incorporates many optimization methods--see the documentation pages for `FindMinimum` (local/gradient optimizer, including Newton's method) and `NMinimize` (global/derivative-free optimizer). If you really want to code your own implementation (which should not be difficult), see the documentation for the function `D`. This will give you your Jacobian and Hessian directly.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your response. Unfortunately at this moment I'm failing at a very basic level which makes it hard to show the effort. Anyways I'm not asking for a finished implementation.

Comment: Jacobian and Hessian are also given here: tutorial/Differentiation (note that many of these sorts of things are often hard to find unless you already know they are there)

Comment: To be sure: The page @MikeHoneychurch mentions is the one you get if you enter those keywords in the Mathematica Documentation Center (in the Help menu). On the internet that would be: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Differentiation.html

Answer (score 34):

Your solution was almost correct, except that it should make `f` an argument of the hessian function and could implement the derivatives in a more compact way. As pointed out by Mike Honeychurch in the above comments, the first place to start would be to look at the [documentation on differentiation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Differentiation.html).

Here is how the derivative operator `D` can be used to define gradients and hessians:

```
Clear[f, hessian]
```

Gradient:

```
D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]
```

> $\left\{f^{(1,0)}(x,y),f^{(0,1)}(x,y)\right\}$

Hessian (alternative formulation `D[f[x,y],{{x,y},2}]`):

```
D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}, {{x, y}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  f^{(2,0)}(x,y) & f^{(1,1)}(x,y) \\
>  f^{(1,1)}(x,y) & f^{(0,2)}(x,y) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Now to define the latter as an operator:

```
hessian[x_, y_] = Function[{f},
   D[f, {{x, y}}, {{x, y}}]
   ];


f[x_, y_] := (x^2 - y)/(x^2 + y^2 + 1);

hessian[x, y][f[x, y]]//FullSimplify
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -\frac{2 \left(3 x^2-y^2-1\right)
>    \left(y^2+y+1\right)}{\left(x^2+
>    y^2+1\right)^3} & \frac{2 x
>    \left((2 y+1) x^2-y (y (2
>    y+3)+2)+1\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+
>    1\right)^3} \\
>  \frac{2 x \left((2 y+1) x^2-y (y
>    (2
>    y+3)+2)+1\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+
>    1\right)^3} & -\frac{2
>    \left(x^4+(1-3 y (y+1))
>    x^2+y^3-3
>    y\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)
>    ^3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

To plug in specific values for `x` and `y`, one approach would be to follow the last result by

```
%/.{x->2,y->3}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -\frac{13}{686} & -\frac{29}{343}
>    \\
>  -\frac{29}{343} & \frac{53}{686}
>    \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Here, the `%` recalls the result of the previous output, and the `/.` stands for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

**Edit: generalization to n-th derivative**

To generalize the Hessian above, you can get the tensor of `n`-th derivatives as follows:

```
D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, n}]
```

where `n` is the order of the derivative. For example, with `n=3` you get

```
Clear[f];
D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 3}] // TableForm
```

> [image: matrix]

Comment: Hello, I share the OP's noobness. I have a question. Can I actually do this on the wolfram alpha website itself? It only shows me one line where I can input stuff... or do I have to buy the full blown Mathematica software? Thanks.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond It also works in Alpha if you input the one-line command including the function definition: `D[x^2 - y)/(x^2 + y^2 + 1), {{x, y}}, {{x, y}}]`

Comment: Quite a long time now, perhaps @Jens code can be reduce a bit by:    
    D[x^2 - y)/(x^2 + y^2 + 1), {{x, y}}, 2}] //FullSimplify

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is a bit old but Wolfram [has an official solution on their *MathWorld* website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html) which I've tested and it works well.

Just use the following function:

```
HessianH[f_, x_List?VectorQ] := D[f, {x, 2}]
```

It's used like one would expect:

```
(* Your function *)
f[x_, y_, z_] := 100*(y - x^2) + (1 - x)^2 + 100 (z - y^2) + (1 - y)^2

(* Just pass whatev vars you want to compute the Hessian of *)
HessianH[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Samuel, I know this is a bit old, but the documentation for the function `Grad` gives an even simpler solution, by simple repeated application (and which allows use of curvilinear coordinates etc.):

```
Grad[Grad[f[x,y,z],{x,y,z}],{x,y,z}]
```

Comment: In what way is this superior to `D[f[x,y,z],{{x,y,z},2}]`?