# Derivative of vector dot product with respect to a vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, expression-manipulation, vector-calculus

I have the expression:

```
Transpose[gvecI, {2, 1}].x (m[1] + m[2])
```

`gvecI` and `x` are [3x1] vectors while `m[1]` and `m[2]` are scalars, not important for this problem other than to point out that the solution should handle the existence of multiplication by scalars in the expression. I need to take a derivative with respect to x. Currently I have:

```
In= D[Transpose[gvecI, {2, 1}].x (m[1] + m[2]), x]
Out= Transpose[gvecI, {2, 1}].1 (m[1] + m[2])
```

**However**, I need instead:

```
Out= IdentityMatrix[3].gvecI (m[1]+m[2])
```

This is because we know from math that:

$$
\vec \nabla(\vec g\cdot\vec x)=[\vec\nabla(\vec g)]\vec x+[\vec\nabla(\vec x)]\vec g
$$

What is the appropriate operation in Mathematica? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some quantities are undefined and their dimensions thus unclear. In the absence of that info, my best guess is that this is a possible duplicate of [Quick Hessian matrix and gradient calculation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19611/quick-hessian-matrix-and-gradient-calculation), specialized to `n=1` (i.e., first derivatives).

Comment: @Jens, as I said they are 3x1 lists. I updated the quesiton to include the definition of `m[1]` and `m[2]`. It is not the same as the Hessian calculation as I want to keep things fully symbolic (i.e. indicate a derivative rather than actually do one).

Comment: It's easier for people to get started on this if you give examples of `gvecI` and `x`. Otherwise it's not clear if they have values at all, or are supposed to be just symbols about which we make certain assumptions.

Comment: @Jens they are just symbols that should behave as [3x1] vectors. The values can be anything, but the whole point is that I do not want them to have values - I want the operation to be done on the raw symbols, as the LaTeX equation shows.

Comment: OK, then I initially misunderstood your question. It's not a duplicate of the Q I linked earlier.

Comment: @Jens No problem. I wish it was... I need the solution and I can't figure out how.

Comment: I have the same problem. It is 2019 now. seems no progress over the last four years.