# ArgMax, FindArgMax, and NArgMax disagreeing on answer

Tags: mathematical-optimization

In working on an estimation problem, I created three Gaussian-like functions. The ML estimate could be seen as the argmax of the product of the three functions. In trying to get the code to run faster, I discovered complementary functions to `ArgMax`: `NArgMax`, and `FindArgMax`. However, I can not get the functions `NArgMax` and `FindArgMax`to agree with the `ArgMax` solution. For reference, I believe that the `ArgMax` solution is correct, and the other two are not. Without pasting all of my code, here is a MWE that demonstrates the effect:

```
test1[x_, y_] := 1/.01^2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/0.01^2]
test2[x_, y_] := 1/.1^2*Exp[-((x - 5)^2 + (y - 3)^2)/0.1^2]
ArgMax[test1[x, y] test2[x, y], {x, y}] // AbsoluteTiming
FindArgMax[
  test1[x, y]*test2[x, y], {{x, 2.5}, {y, 1.5}}] // AbsoluteTiming
NArgMax[test1[x, y] test2[x, y], {x, y}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The results are

```
{0.0388864, {0.049505, 0.029703}}
{0.102196, {2.5, 1.5}}
{0.0687933, {1.02414*10^30, 8.98768*10^29}}
```

However, it is worth noting that `FindArgMax` throws the warning: `FindArgMax::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a maximum; it may be a minimum or a saddle point. >>`. `NArgMax` does not produce any warnings or errors.

I believe this warning may be the reason that neither `FindArgMax` nor `NArgMax` find the proper solution: `FindArgMax` simply considers the initial estimate to be the final solution (as it warns), but I do not know why `NArgMax` returns such large values for its solution. However, `ArgMax` does correctly identify the maximum.

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is `AbsoluteTiming` relevant to the question?

Comment: It isn't really relevant to the question, it was more me trying to figure out which would be faster, if they were in agreement. I didn't remove it because `AbsoluteTiming` is well documented and I figured it didn't really matter. I can remove it, if you think it really detracts from the question.

Comment: Your test function `test1[x, y] * test2[x, y]` produces ridiculously small numbers for any `x` and `y`. I guess none of the results are correct.

Comment: No, I'm fairly certain that the result produced by `ArgMax` is correct. The size of the numeric solution shouldn't matter. If you let the variance of `test1` equal the variance of `test2`, the ML estimate should be the midpoint of the two centroids, which is what it produces in that case; and `FindArgMax` also would 'find' that result, although that is its initial estimate.

Comment: OK. My next guess is that since numerically `test1[x, y] * test2[x, y]` is very small, numerical methods by `FindArgMax` and `NArgMax` wouldn't work. Only an exact method done by `ArgMax` would.

Comment: Also, you can change `test2` to produce larger values overall by changing its center to `(0.25,0.25)`, and I still do not get correct answers, e.g. `test2[x_, y_] := 1/.1^2*Exp[-((x - .25)^2 + (y - .25)^2)/0.1^2]`

Comment: try using exact values (100^2 instead of 1/.01^2) and increasing workingprecision

Comment: Indeed `NArgMax[test1[x, y] * test2[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]` for example helps even without using exact numbers.

Comment: Ok. So changing `WorkingPrecision` does actually help make both `NArgMax` and `FindArgMax` work, assuming your estimate for `FindArgMax` is close enough. This is the first time that changing `WorkingPrecision` has actually helped me resolve a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Well, on further review, even setting `WorkingPrecision->2` works better than whatever the default is. Why would that be?

Comment: I can't reproduce `WorkingPrecision->2` producing a good result. (I wouldn't  call a wrong result w/o warnings an improvement). Anyway is this a real problem? `ArgMax` works, use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) in the comment, it is adviseable to use arbitrary-precision numbers in this case, so we can set `WorkingPrecision` however high.

```
test1[x_, y_] := 1/(1/100)^2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/(1/100)^2]
test2[x_, y_] := 1/(1/10)^2*Exp[-((x - 5)^2 + (y - 3)^2)/(1/10)^2]
f[x_, y_] := test1[x_, y_] * test2[x_, y_]
```

Then, for example,

```
NArgMax[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

gives a result that agrees with that given by `ArgMax`.

As to `FindArgMax`, it's a little more tricky. Even

```
FindArgMax[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 10000]
```

doesn't help. We can improve that by manually supplying [the gradient and Hessian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19611/quick-hessian-matrix-and-gradient-calculation):

```
grad = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]
hess = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}, {{x, y}}]
FindArgMax[
  f[x, y],
  {x, y},
  Gradient -> grad, 
  Method -> {"Newton", Hessian -> hess},
  WorkingPrecision -> 10000
]
```

`FindArgMax` now gives a result that agrees with that given by `ArgMax`.

Comment: That 'fix' for `FindArgMax` still requires ridiculously high `WorkingPrecision`. Simply changing the estimate is a simpler and easier way of getting `FindArgMax` to be in agreement. Furthermore, there is the issue that I pointed out, that even setting `WorkingPrecision -> 2` for `NArgMax` allows it to find the solution properly. Why would that help? A precision of 2 digits is extremely low, yet it allows `NArgMax` to converge.

Comment: I don't know why `NArgMax` works with low `WorkingPrecision` and `FindArgMax` requires high `WorkingPrecision`. What did you mean by saying that 'that fix ... *still* requires ridiculously high `WorkingPrecision`'? Does the fix *not* resolve your problem as asked for in the question?

Comment: Well I mean, it works now. But the default `WorkingPrecision` is `MachinePrecision`, which is roughly 15.95. So setting `WorkingPrecision` to 2 shouldn't really help, yet it does. So, yes it resolves the problem, but only raises more questions.

Comment: Indeed it's interesting to investigate further why that's the case. Also strange is that `NArgMax[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]` gives the result that agrees with `ArgMax`, while `NArgMax[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]` doesn't!