# Get the coefficient matrix from a quadratic form

Tags: matrix, polynomials

Suppose I have a quadratic form of

```
qf = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + 2 d x y + 2 e x z + 2 f y z
```

How can I easily to get the **symmetric** matrix A, such that $X^TAX=qf$? where $X^T=(x,y,z)$.

I hope that the method will work for general quadratic form (i.e., for 2nd-homogenous polynomial of variable x,y,z,w,...)

I have tried the function `CoefficientRules`, but it seem there needs a step to transform the order of each term into the "position" of matrix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need `CoefficientArrays`:

```
mat = Last@CoefficientArrays[qf, {x, y, z}, "Symmetric"->True];
{x, y, z}.mat.{x, y, z} == qf // Simplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: I need `mat` be symmetric (and I re-edit the question).

Comment: Ok, I find the option `"Symmetric" -> True`, please update your answer?

Comment: @vanabel  thank you for pointing out this option. Embarrassing ignorance. :)

Comment: @vanabel Edited :)

Answer (score 22):

Here is a very short solution:

```
qf = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + 2 d x y + 2 e x z + 2 f y z;

1/2 D[qf, {{x, y, z}, 2}]
(* ==> {{a, d, e}, {d, b, f}, {e, f, c}} *)
```

This is just an application of the answer to [Quick Hessian matrix and gradient calculation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19611/245).

Comment: Very slick! (+1)

Comment: @Jens  neat +1 :)

Comment: good idea (and trick)!

Comment: Can anyone explain to me the rationality of this answer ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way that yields symmetric matrix (for this example you could just write it down):

```
m=Module[{r = {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3}, tu = Tuples[{x, y, z}, 2]},
 Normal@SparseArray[(## /. r) -> 
      Coefficient[qf, Times @@ ##]/(2 - Boole[#[[1]] === #[[2]]]) & /@
     tu, {3, 3}]]
```

yields:

```
{{a, d, e}, {d, b, f}, {e, f, c}}
```

Check:

```
Expand[{x, y, z}.m.{x, y, z}]
```

yields `qf`

`CoefficientArrays` as per @xzczd yields:

```
{{a, 2 d, 2 e}, {0, b, 2 f}, {0, 0, c}}
```

which is also a valid representation.