# Writting a Hessian for an arbitrary number of variables or for a arbitrary vectorial function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following code calculate the Hessian --- with simplification --- for a transcendental function.

```
fu[x_, y_, z_] :=  x^α y^β z^γ
hes = D[#1[#2, #3, #4], {{#2, #3, #4}}, {{#2, #3, #4}}] &
hescd = hes[fu, x, y, 
    z] /. {x_^(α_ - 2) y_^β_ z_^γ_ -> U/x^2, 
    x_^(α_ - 1) y_^(β_ - 1) z_^γ_ -> U/(x y)};
hescd // MatrixForm
```

I would like

1) to generalize it for a vector of arbitrary dimension

2) It obviously works  for any algebraic function but not for all the transcendental functions for which there is a simplification. How to rewrite it to include directly in `hes` the simplification?

Comment: Related: [Quick Hessian matrix and gradient calculation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19611/245)

Comment: I'm probably being dense here, but what is `U`?

Comment: @ChrisK It seems to stand for the entire function. It's an odd sort of simplification for programming, but common enough in papers

Comment: To be fair, the OP neglected to mention that `U` was supposed to be a stand-in for the entire function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for the Cobb-Douglass function with arbitrary number of variables:

```
ClearAll[fu2, hess2]
fu2[x : {__}, p : {__}] := Times @@ (x^p)

hess2[fn_, x : {__}, p : {__}] := ReleaseHold[D[fn[x, p], {x, 2}] /. 
  Power[w_, Plus[k_Integer, a_]] :>  HoldForm[Power[w, k]] Power[w, a] /. fn[x, p] :> U]

hess2[fu2, {v, w, x, y, z}, {a, b, c, d, e}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 10 and later versions you can use `Inactive` and `Activate` combination instead of `HoldForm` and  `ReleaseHold`, that is,

```
hess2[fn_, x : {__}, p : {__}] := Activate[D[fn[x, p], {x, 2}] /. 
  Power[w_, Plus[k_Integer, a_]] :>  Inactive[Power[w, k]] Power[w, a] /. fn[x, p] :> U]
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want the following:

```
hess[fn_, varList__] := Simplify[D[fn @@ {varList}, {{varList}, 2}]]
```

The first argument is the function, and the remaining arguments are referred to by `varList__`. Its length is arbitrary, and the function is applied to it by `@@`.

I added `Simplify` to address your point 2). It could be replaced by `FullSimplify` or some other, more customized commands that depend on the specific application.

**Edit**

I initially only went by the title of the question. The more specific replacement in the question can be built into my original answer by adding the following rule:

```
hess[fn_, varList__] := U ( D[fn @@ #, {#, 2}] /. Thread[# -> 1])/
                            KroneckerProduct[#, #] &[#] &@{varList}
```

This maintains the calling syntax given in the question, and works for arbitrary dimensions:

```
fu[w_, x_, y_, z_] := w^a x^b y^c z^d

hess[fu, w, x, y, z] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The output is the same as in @MichaelE2's answer.

Comment: Jens it works and it does not work. It works because it do the trick. But it does not work since the simplification is not done. My problem is to do the suggested simplification for a fonction of any length --- not only x^α y^β z^γ but also x^\[Alpha] y^\[Beta] z^\[Gamma] v^\[Epsilon] and so on

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki OK, I added your specific simplification.

Answer (score 4):

The Hessian is pretty straightforward, as pointed out by Jens.  Using patterns instead of basic algebra makes the "simplification" trickier than necessary.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, w, x, y, z, f];

f[x_List, p_List] := Inner[Power, x, p, Times];

vars = {w, x, y, z};
powers = {a, b, c, d};

D[f[vars, powers], {vars, 2}] * U/f[vars, powers] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]