# Taylor expansion in higher dimensions with non-commutative tensor products

Tags: series-expansion, tensors

I would like to perform Taylor expansion of functions

$$f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

I was wondering how I can force Mathematica to handle the non-commutativity of the resulting tensor products. Following is an example:

Suppose $x, \delta \in \mathbb{R}^n; h \in \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x+h\delta) = f(x) + h f'(x)\delta+ \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x) \,\,\,(\delta, \delta)\quad ...$$

In the above expansion, $f'(x)$ is the Jacobian acting on $\delta$;  $f''(x)$ is a 3-tensor acting on the vectors $\delta$ and $\delta$.

Comment: What are non-commutative tensor products you talking about?

Comment: I think he means products between tensors $\delta $ of different orders.

Comment: You have to specify $f$, $x$, and $\delta$ as `Array`s with the correct dimensions to let `Series` know the structure. It won't deduce it on its own for arbitrary symbolic objects.

Comment: @Jens Can you show me a quick example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't know for sure if a solution with explicitly specified dimensions is what you're looking for, here is a way to get the results in that case:

```
δ = Array["δ", 3];
x = Array["x", 3];
f = Table["f"[i] @@ ##, {i, 3}] &;

f[x]
```

[image: f]

The components of the vectors are labeled by integers, e.g., `f[1]` is the first component of the function `f`, and it depends on the argument `x` which has `3` components itself. To distinguish component names from the variables containing the vectors, I use `String`s `"x"`, `"f"`. You could also choose completely different names, but strings are nice if you don't plan to assign values to the symbolic components.

With these definitions for the variable `x`, offset `δ` and function `f` as 3-vectors, we can now do the Taylor expansion. To collect the desired tensors, I first get the `SeriesCoefficient` for each order `n` (here from `0` to `2`). That's a 3-vector. Then do the `n`-th vectorial derivative of that coefficient vector with `D[..., {δ, n}]`. See also [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19615/245). This notation causes `D` to return the tensor of the correct rank, as you can see from the output of `Dimensions`:

```
tensors = 
  Table[D[SeriesCoefficient[f[x + h δ], {h, 0, n}], {δ, n}], {n, 0, 2}];

Map[Dimensions, tensors]
```

> $\{\{3\},\{3,3\},\{3,3,3\}\}$

To verify that this is indeed the correct set of tensors, let's see if the formula in the question is reproduced to the order I have chosen here (`2`):

```
Simplify[
 Normal[Series[f[x + h δ], {h, 0, 2}]] == 
  tensors[[1]] + h tensors[[2]].δ + h^2/2 tensors[[3]].δ.δ]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thanks! I have accepted your answer. I will see if I can make this work with my needs