# Factorising blinear forms with Mathematica

Tags: symbolic

Say I have some symbolic output that looks like the following:

```
expr = A a1 b1 + B a1 b2 + C a2 b1 + D a2 b2
```

I would like to factorise this in the following way:

Input: `FactorQuadratic[expr, {a1, a2}, {b1, b2}]`

Output: `{ { A, B }, { C, D } }`

In such a way that $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 &  a_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b1\\b2\end{bmatrix}$ is equal to the original expression.

Is there a function that does this, or something like it? The closest I'm aware of is `FactorList`, but I'm not entirely sure how to slice and dice indices on it to make it do what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19615/29734), you can compute the Hessian:

```
D[A a1 b1 + B a1 b2 + C a2 b1 + D a2 b2, {{a1, a2}}, {{b1, b2}}]
(* {{A, B}, {C, D}} *)
```

Comment: Accepted this one since it's shorter, and has an obvious behavior in the case that a1=b1, a2=b2.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this:

```
expr = $A a1 b1 + $B a1 b2 + $C a2 b1 + $D a2 b2;
v1 = {a1, a2};
v2 = {b1, b2};

Last@CoefficientArrays[#, v2] & /@ 
  Last@CoefficientArrays[expr, v1] // Normal

(*  {{$A, $B}, {$C, $D}}  *)
```

Note `C` and `D` are protected symbols and not meant to be used as user parameters.